# Multiple webcams on a single Raspberry Pi

Tags: webcam

I want to have multiple USB webcams running on a single Raspberry Pi. I will put them through a powered hub. I want the webcams to take stills simultaneously (or as simultaneously as possible - a second or two delay isn't a big deal) and save the images to a memory stick, each image will have the same name beginning but then `cam1`, `cam2`, `cam3` etc. to differentiate them from each other.

Is this possible? If so, what number of webcams am I limited to? Also, how would I address them, can `fswebcam` control more than one webcam?

If it isn't possible, can anyone tell me why not?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but worth looking at: #1: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32965/5538 #2: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/33247/5538

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretically, yes. It's possible to connect as many webcams as you can as long as they're powered up as per their requirements.

`How do you address them ?`

Each usb web cam that you connect gets listed under `/dev/video<n>` where n = 0,1,2 .. as number of video devices increase. Ie, if I connect two webcams to my system, I would be able to see two entries `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1` when I fire `ls /dev/video*`.

I've not used `fswebcam` personally but its documentation suggests that using `-d` flag you can specify a particular webcam. Default is `/dev/video0`. You can run multiple instances of fswebcam to capture images from all the cams simultaneously.

However, USB bandwidth bottleneck is entirely a different issue as you keep on adding devices.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you. I will crack on and see if I can make it work.

Comment: @MattHowarth Glad that it helped. You may want to upvote / mark it as the right answer if it answers your query. :)

Comment: Hi Dastaan, I have given it the tick, but I can't increase the vote because I'm new to the group, I will up vote it as soon as I can. It definitely answers my questions, thanks again: )

Answer (score 2):

thank you dastaan, your answer help me so much, finally I take a picture with 
`fswebcam --device <device> <filename>`

here is the example, I'm gonna take a picture and save it to image.jpg:

my first webcam

```
fswebcam --device /dev/video0 image.jpg
```

and my second webcam

```
fswebcam --device /dev/video1 image.jpg
```

you can check your device with

```
ls /dev/
```

hope it helped for the others

Comment: Hello and welcome. I have edited your answer according to some formatting styles we use here... and removed the `.` which I thought wrong. If something does not add up with the edit feel free to roll back or correct.